# Linked directory not found

Tags: c++, windows

I have following scenario:

The main software I wrote uses a database created by a simulator. This database is around 10 GB big at the moment, so I want to keep only one copy of that data per system.

Assuming I have following projects:

Main Software using the data, located at /SimData

DLL using the data for debugging, searching for data at /SimData

Debugging tool to parse the image database, searching for the data at /SimData

Since I do not want to have all those programs have their own copy of SimData (not only to decrease place used, but also to ensure that all Simulation data used is always up to date for all programs).

I created for the DLL and Debugging Utility a link named SimData to MainSoftware/SimData, but when opening a file with "SimData\MyFile.data" it cannot find it, only the MainSoftware with the ACTUAL SimData folder can find it.

How can I use the MainSoftware/SimData folder without setting absolute paths?

This is on Windows 7 x64

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with Peter about adding the DB location as a configurable parameter. A common place to store that is in the registry.

however, If you want to create links that will be recognized by your software, try hardlinks. . fsutil should do the trick as described [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc788097.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

You need a way to configure the database location.  You could use an INI or other configuration file, or a registry setting, or a command-line input, or an environment variable.  Or You could write your program to search a directory hierarchy... for example, if the various modules are usually siblings of each other in your directory tree, you could search for SimData/MyFile.data, ../SimData/MyFile.data, ../../MainSoftware/SimData/Myfile.data, and use the first one found.

Which answer is the "right one" depends on your situation.

Comment: So it's not possible to create a link to that folder that C++ sees as a folder which it can use?